# Is the class org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler in apache-nutch-1.12?

Tags: nutch

I've installed nutch for the first time. Installation and set up seemed pretty smooth. I have it running on Windows 7. I setup the classpath for the nutch installation. After seeing the error shown below (missing main class), I trouble shot the setup for some time.

```
C:\Users\Public\PublicApps\apache-nutch-1.12>nutch.bat crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 1 > crawl.log Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler
```

Finally, I searched through the nutch jar files. I don't see the org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler class in the jars anywhere. Checked several times. I'm stumped.

I am assuming that class should be in the download distribution found at http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/nutch/1.12/apache-nutch-1.12-bin.zip

Perhaps there is something simple that I've overlooked.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class o.a.n.crawl.Crawl (in Nutch 2.x "Crawler") has been replaced by a shell script (bin/crawl) which is more adaptable, see [NUTCH-1087](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1087).

Comment: Sebastian, thank you for the pointer. Yep, that cleared it up.